# how to get the foreignkey attribute value

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to print out the email related to a specific OrderItem for a Customer, I've followed the logic from the answer below and I get the terminology but I'm definitely missing something, can't figure out what exactly, as of now I get the error `name 'email' is not defined`

```
#Models

class Customer(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    object_one = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    object_two= models.BooleanField(default=False)


#View

@receiver(pre_save, sender=OrderItem)
def order_item_pre_save(instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.object_one is not None and instance.object_two==True:

        customer_email = OrderItem.objects.filter(order__customer__email=email)
        print(customer_email)

        print(instance.object_one)
    else:
        print("object_one not provided")

#Traceback

Exception Type: NameError at /admin/main/order/126/change/
Exception Value: name 'email' is not defined
```

Comment: This code sample is incomplete. Also, you're trying to get orders whose email is literally `email`.

Comment: @pigrammer please have a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple `OrderItem`s for such customer. You filter with:

```
def test():
    email = 'foo@bar.com'
    customer_email = OrderItem.objects.filter(order__customer__email=email)
    print(customer_email)
```

If you have an `OrderItem` object you use:

```
myorderitem.order.customer.email
```

Comment: How would I retrieve the specific email tho? thx!

Comment: @betty_: but you already *got* the `email`, since your are filtering on it?

Comment: yh I understand, my problem is actually accessing that email, you defined it as 'foo@bar.com' but removing that I believe I would get an email not defined error

Comment: @betty_: if you have an `OrderItem` object named `myorderitem`, see the code fragment below.

Comment: I finally am able to fully understand and fix my problem, thank you so much!